# How do I change the background color (specifically on shapes) of CSS hover?

Tags: css

This is my code and this is the navigation bar, created with Wordpress PHP.

Navigation bar without hover:

http://postimg.org/image/awr4dlok5/

When I hover, it wont follow the shape of the navigation bar. I wanted it to have rounded corners. Please help.

This is how it should look:

http://postimg.org/image/jhks7djnz/

Thank you :) (Ignore background, just some random anime pics)

```
.site-nav {
    height: 50px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(72, 55, 35);
    background: rgba(72, 55, 35, .75);
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.site-nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.site-nav ul:before, .site-nav:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
}
.site-nav ul:after {
    clear: both;
}
.site-nav ul {
    *zoom: 1;
}
.site-nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    height: 50px;
}
.site-nav ul li a:link, .site-nav ul li a:visited {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.site-nav ul li a:hover {
    background:rgba(72, 55, 35, 0.4);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a border radius on the element you're hovering over to match the parent.  You only need this on the first menu element, and you only want the top and bottom left to have a radius applied.

The following should do the trick:

```
.site-nav ul li a:first-child{
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
.site-nav ul li a:hover{
     background:rgba(72,55,35,0.4);
}
```

You are changing the background of `.site-nav ul li a` tag.

Comment: @SW4 can you help me in wordpress coding?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the radius to the first menu item as well.

```
.site-nav ul li:first-child 
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;   
    border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
}
```

Adding the above to the css should work

EDIT: If it doesn't work with the above style try this one:

```
.site-nav ul li:first-child a 
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;   
    border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
}

.site-nav ul li:first-child a:hover
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;   
    border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a `border-radius` to the element when hovering.

**CSS:**

Change

```
.site-nav ul li a:hover {
    background:rgba(72, 55, 35, 0.4);
}
```

to

```
.site-nav ul li a:hover {
    background:rgba(72, 55, 35, 0.4);
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
```

This would fit perfectly (if using the correct border-radius amount) for the `Home` button.

If you want to add rounded corners for all corners of the element (not just the top and bottom left like above), just use this:

```
.site-nav ul li a:hover {
    background:rgba(72, 55, 35, 0.4);
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

EDIT: When looking at your navigation bar, only the first element (e.g. the `Home` button) needs this border-radius, the other buttons have straight corners. You could do the following (instead of the above) to only apply these rounded corners on the `Home` button:

```
.site-nav ul li:first-child a:hover {
    background:rgba(72, 55, 35, 0.4);
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
```

By selecting `li:first-child`, only the first `li` element of the list will have this CSS applied.

Comment: can you help me in wordpress coding?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wordpress, though I am with HTML, CSS and a couple of other computer languages. But when you encounter another problem and you can explain it thoroughly, why not ask it here on SO?